# Call ASP.NET's input validation after using ValidateInput(false)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I bash my hands on special characters in the entry fields of my form, when I hit submit, all I get back is a blank page, as ASP.NET detected potentially malicious input and threw an error into my Event Log, all before reaching my MVC controller action.

I would much rather return an error to the user, so they don't just get a blank page. So I want to use ValidateInput(false) and then call the validator from inside my code, so I can send a response. How do I call the validator from an ASP.NET MVC action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am little confused with your question .Are you looking for invoking the code which does the model validation ? IF yes you can do that by checking the ModelState.IsValid property. If any of your validation fails, it will return false and in your view you will see the error messages. You can also specify some custom error message from your action method as well if you want to do so.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      //Model validation is successful. Proceed to other stuff

      //If you want to return some custom error message, do like this
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name is deactivated");

    }
 return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to validate input at server side?

You can use client side validation, you need to add regular expression attribute on your model property and set a nice error message for it. like below

```
[RegularExpression("your regex", ErrorMessage = @"please check your input .... ")]
public string MyInput { get; set; }
```